# Missing Child Elements With One-To-Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my code I'm getting back a `List<TableA>`

TableA class definition

```
class TableA {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Child>? Children{ get; set; }

}
```

Child table has 2 columns: TableAID, and TableBID. The PK is a composite key referencing both of these columns . TableAID is a FK referencing dbo.TableA.ID and TableBID is a FK referencing dbo.TableB.ID

Child class definition:

```
class Child
    {
        public int TableAID { get; set; }

        public int TableBID { get; set; }

        public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }

    }
```

Child table data:

| TableAID | TableBID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |

This is my model setup code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
                .HasKey(c=> new { c.TableAID, c.TableBID  });


            modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>()
               .HasKey(a => a.ID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>()
                .HasMany(a => a.Children)
                .WithOne(a => a.TableA)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.TableAID);
```

When I retrieve the list of type `TableA`, I'm getting back 2 TableA elements. For the first element, TableA of ID 1, the Children property has 2 elements in it, which is working as designed. But for the second element, Table A of ID 2, I get back no child elements (empty list), even though there exists a child element that has a TableAID of 2. I can't figure out why this is happening. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: `entity-framework` is the parent tag.  It should always be present along with a version-specific tag.

Comment: How are you loading the related entities?  If you don't use `Include`, etc, they won't be loaded, and a few Child entities might have been loaded previously.

Comment: Yes, if you haven't eager loaded related entities with `Include` then the DbContext will still attempt to provide references to children it is already tracking resulting in an incomplete picture.  `var data = Context.TableAs.Include(x => x.Children).ToList()`. The other thing to check is that the connection string used at runtime is pointing at the same database you are checking.

Comment: Using Entity Framework Core 5.05 and yes I'm using .Include()

Comment: Where is your tableB , pls post it too

Answer (score 0):

all together should be like this

```
class TableA {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Child> Children{ get; set; }

}

class TableB {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Child> Children{ get; set; }

}

class Child
    {
        public int TableAID { get; set; }

        public int TableBID { get; set; }

        public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
        public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }

    }
```